# In minicom, how do I get more time to stop autoboot so I can enter u-boot?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, embedded-linux, u-boot, busybox

I have BusyBox v1.24.2 running in Ubuntu 14.04.  When I reboot I get a prompt that says, "Hit any key to stop autoboot: 3".  Normally I get 3 seconds but now it gives me a 0 count and immediately goes into autoboot giving me no chance to enter u-boot.  Is there a way to increase the time?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Ubuntu or minicom or Busybox. The ""Hit any key to stop autoboot" prompt comes from U-Boot. U-Boot is already in control of your SBC system at that point. What does *"but now it gives me a 0 count"* mean? Are you are claiming that you used to be able to stop the autoboot, but now that has changed?  What's the difference between *"normally"* and *"now"*, i.e. what did you change that you're not mentioning?

Comment: @sawdust "but now it gives me a 0 count" means that when I normally get "Hit any key to stop autoboot: 3" I now get "Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0".  What I changed that I didn't mention was the firmware configuration on the board.  I didn't realize at the time that the firmware configuration is what determines the U-Boot environment variables.  It would be nice if you would give me a chance to respond before you vote down my question.

Comment: The down vote is incentive to clarify & update your question with salient details.   Now that you have provided a tiny bit of clarification that the prompt message is different, that would indicate that you somehow modified an environment variable.  So what exactly is this *"firmware configuration"*?  There's a complicated solution, but there may be a simpler solution if you can explain what you did.  Also helpful would be the details about the SBC, such as what is the boot medium, e.g. where are the environment variables stored?

Comment: @sawdust I'm working with an embedded Linux board.  I load different firmware configurations to the board depending on the project I'm working on.  This was the first time I downloaded this particular firmware and had not encountered this issue before.  The board runs on an ARMv7 cpu.  To be honest I don't know where the environment variables are stored.  I just pull them up using printenv or fw_printenv depending on if I'm in U-Boot or Linux.

Comment: Since you already have the **fw_printenv** utility in your Linux environment, then you probably also have **fw_setenv**.  So then you can use the advice from Brendan answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to modify your u-boot environment variable; `bootcmd` and add `bootdelay=x` (where x is the number of seconds).

You can do this by interrupting the boot sequence and modifying the u-boot environment variable here, or whilst in userspace use `fw_setenv` to achieve this.

More information here regarding the `bootdelay` environment variable: https://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootEnvVariables